# Stripe framework always returns @1x images for card brands

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

Stripe always returns @1x small images of card brands.

What I want is it should pick it's @2x,@3x images based on the device resolution.

Here is my code.

```
let cardBrand = STPCardValidator.brand(forNumber: cardNumber)
let cardImage = STPImageLibrary.brandImage(for: cardBrand)

self.IBImageViewCardType?.image = cardImage
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Stripe, they will return images of size 32*20 pixels.

Check the docs [here](https://stripe.github.io/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPImageLibrary.html).

If you are looking to get images of bigger size then you will need to create your own implementation.

Add the larger size assets, Get the card type and set the image.

You can implement like below

```
func setImage(_ card : String) {              
                switch card {

                case CardType.Visa.rawValue:

                case CardType.MasterCard.rawValue:

                case CardType.Amex.rawValue:

                case CardType.JCB.rawValue:

                case CardType.Discover.rawValue:

                case CardType.Diners.rawValue:

                case CardType.Maestro.rawValue:

                case CardType.Electron.rawValue:

                case CardType.Dankort.rawValue:

                case CardType.UnionPay.rawValue:

                case CardType.RuPay.rawValue:


                case CardType.Unknown.rawValue:

                default:


                    break
                }
}
```